# Passing .sql file to Postgresql psql command

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to run the following `file.sql` using psql command (Postgresql v8.4):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS 
 SELECT * FROM MY_ORDER_TABLE;
```

This is the command that I use:

```
psql -d myDB -f file.sql
```

But I get the following error:

```
psql:file.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe there is a BOM (ByteOrderMark) in your file.sql ? (use `hexdump -C file.sql` to find out)

Comment: Thanks wildplasser!, that fixed the problem. I used PgAdmin to create .sql files and it adds 'BOM' to the beginning of the file.

Comment: BTW: I cannot reproduce the problem. Did you actually type the query in in pgadmin, or did you import an existing file?

Comment: I used 'Query tool' in pgAdmin3 (pgAdmin3->Tools->Query tool) and created a new sql file. Even if you create a blank new sql file, it adds a BOM in the beginning of the file.